# Translation for the plugin using redux framework does not work

Tags: plugins, translation

I am working on a commercial plugin and i integrated redux in it and use it as my option panel, i am almost done with the plugin, i started to translate the plugin but the translation does not work, i do all things correctly in my plugins function.php and still not want to work
i add this to my plugin functions

```
load_plugin_textdomain('my_plugin_name', false, basename( dirname( FILE ) ) . '/languages' );
```

and make all strings translatable but it does not work, i asked this question on redux github reposity but no helping answer, they say to call last function before calling redux but still not work, any one have an idea.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you please share any of your string, we want to see how your used the gettext function.

Comment: i use  __('Hello world','my_plugin_name') or _e('Hello worl','my_plugin_name')